# Documentation main page like in Python doc or Sphinx doc?

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

I trying to get the effect obtained on Python and Sphinx main pages of documentation. I mean the table of contents structure. Is there any keyword for toctree to get similar effect or I have to do this manually? I tried to find something in the documentation but without any success and sadly the main page of Sphinx documentation doesn't provide the source of rst file.

Any ideas?

Here is the [Sphinx doc main page](http://sphinx-doc.org/)

I need the format effect from section DOCUMENTATION with members like first steps, search page, contents and general index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sphinx documentation [start page](http://sphinx-doc.org/) is not generated from a reST file; it is built from [Jinja templates](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). The main template is [index.html](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/doc/_templates/index.html). Inheritance is used: index.html extends [layout.html](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/doc/_themes/sphinx13/layout.html), which in turn extends [basic/layout.html](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/themes/basic/layout.html).

In order to get the desired "format effect", you will need to look into themes and templates:

- http://sphinx-doc.org/theming.html
- http://sphinx-doc.org/templating.html